# VS 2010 RC installer crashes

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Has anyone heard of a fix for the VS 2010 RC installer crash? I've seen it mentioned a couple times on Connect, but no word on a work-around.

Comment: You might want to post the actual error you are receiving.  i'm sure there can be more than one...also what OS you are using.

Comment: As Jeremy says, might be all sorts of things, but here's one link: http://blogs.msdn.com/heaths/archive/2010/02/10/verify-iso-before-burning-or-mounting-visual-studio-2010-rc.aspx - I've seen a couple of people hit problems because of dodgy ISOs/DVDs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, you aren't going to believe this.

> Display the language bar at the taskbar, right-click on it and choose settings. Then you remove the hand writing support from the list.
>
> There is a bug in the RC for computers with touch screens, and I guess this is the problem.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/setupprerelease/thread/dbcdcd52-d162-4460-9920-33c9ab54b36f

The funny thing is that I don't have a touch screen.

Comment: Wow that worked!!! I had the same problem. The "Data Execution Prevention"(DEP) would kick-in and stop the installation. 
I was aware of the "touchscreen" issue, but I didn't think it would apply to me.
Now installing VS 2010. Thanks..

Comment: I've seen some odd fixes in my time, but that takes the biscuit! Worked a charm.

Comment: Fixes VS2010 startup crash too, who'd have thought it.

Comment: Thanks this comment was a real life-saver. I can't believe how hard it was to find this info.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar trouble, the installation disk would spin up for a few seconds then power down and nothing.
I tried the above solutions but none worked, eventually found that the "Sonic DLA" utility caused problems, once uninstalled VS2010 installed perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I used Microsoft's vcdcontroltool to mount the ISO image.
using [Virtual clone drive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/download.html) it worked perfectly.